# Xval and Tinymce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, xval

I have a problem on submitting an asp.net mvc form that is using Xval for validation and uses TinyMce as an editor on two text areas.

The TinyMce editor is initialized with the new tinymce jquery plugin and the form validation and submission works perfectly if I remove the editor.

But if I initialize the editor the form is submitted only the **second** time I click the submit button...

When I submit the form the first time I get Xval validation errors on the text areas also if they are not empty(they are marked with the Required attribute).

If I submit the form a second time the form is correctly submitted.
Is this a Xval-Jquery validation-TinyMce bug or I am doing something wrong?

How would you debug a problem like that? I tried with Firebug with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

in the `onclick` of the button (or I assume the `onsubmit` of the `form`) then tinyMCE ensures the value is saved and the validation occurs properly.